# Cannot convert LPCWSTR to LPCSTR?

Tags: c++

I dont understand this error. I've been trying to list the files in a directory but I didn't understand this error.
[image]

This is my code below;

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main() {
        WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
        HANDLE hFindFile;
        LPCWSTR file = L"*.cpp";
    
        hFindFile = FindFirstFile(file,&FindFileData);
    
        if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFindFile)
        {
            cout << "Error in Finding File" << endl;
            cout << "Error - " << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "File Found" << endl;
            wcout << "File Name - " << FindFileData.cFileName << endl;
            wcout << "File Size - " << FindFileData.nFileSizeLow << endl;
        }
    
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Add defines `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` to the command line. Some reading https://stackoverflow.com/q/36395838/3747990

Comment: Windows has this funny fascination with UTF-16, a format the rest of us deposited gracefully in the garbage bin about a decade ago.

Comment: Just don't rely on the compiler choosing the correct version of the FindFirstFile macro for you and invoke the correct function directly: `FindFIrstFileW(file, ...);`

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that 'funny' fascination API dominates, and probably by saying 'rest of us' you just mean you and a bunch of others.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `TCHAR`-based Win32 APIs, which are preprocessor macros that map to either ANSI or UNICODE flavor of functions, struct types, etc.

You are clearly not compiling your project with `UNICODE` defined, so the macros are mapping to their ANSI versions (ie: `WIN32_FIND_DATA` -> `WIN32_FIND_DATAA`, `FindFirstFile()` -> `FindFirstFileA()`, etc).  See [Working with Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings) on MSDN for more details.

You are trying to pass a Unicode string to `FindFirstFileA()`, which expects a narrow ANSI string instead, hence the error.  It is also clear that you are expecting the Unicode version of the APIs, by the fact that you are trying to pass `FindFileData.cFileName` to `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout`.

Try this, using `TCHAR` strings instead, so the code will work with either ANSI or UNICODE compilations (which, to be honest, hasn't been required since the Win9x/ME days. Modern Windows has been a wholly Unicode OS since NT4/XP):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef UNICODE
#define t_cout std::wcout
else
#define t_cout std::cout
#endif

int main() {
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFindFile;
    LPCTSTR file = TEXT("*.cpp");
    
    hFindFile = FindFirstFile(file, &FindFileData);
    
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFindFile)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "Error in Finding File\n";
        std::cout << "Error - " << err << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File Found\n";
        t_cout << TEXT("File Name - ") << FindFileData.cFileName << TEXT('\n');

        ULARGE_INTEGER filesize;
        filesize.LowPart = FindFileData.nFileSizeLow;
        filesize.HighPart = FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh;

        std::cout << "File Size - " << filesize.QuadPart << '\n';

        FindClose(hFindFile);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, use the ANSI API directly:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFindFile;
    LPCSTR file = "*.cpp";
    
    hFindFile = FindFirstFileA(file, &FindFileData);
    
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFindFile)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "Error in Finding File\n";
        std::cout << "Error - " << err << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File Found\n";
        std::cout << "File Name - " << FindFileData.cFileName << '\n';

        ULARGE_INTEGER filesize;
        filesize.LowPart = FindFileData.nFileSizeLow;
        filesize.HighPart = FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh;

        std::cout << "File Size - " << filesize.QuadPart << '\n';

        FindClose(hFindFile);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Or, the Unicode API directly:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFindFile;
    LPCWSTR file = L"*.cpp";
    
    hFindFile = FindFirstFileW(file, &FindFileData);
    
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFindFile)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "Error in Finding File\n";
        std::cout << "Error - " << err << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File Found\n";
        std::wcout << L"File Name - " << FindFileData.cFileName << L'\n';

        ULARGE_INTEGER filesize;
        filesize.LowPart = FindFileData.nFileSizeLow;
        filesize.HighPart = FindFileData.nFileSizeHigh;

        std::cout << "File Size - " << filesize.QuadPart << '\n';

        FindClose(hFindFile);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```